# Why does an additional primary current exist in a loaded transformer?

Tags: voltage, current, transformer, winding, flux

I think this has something to do with Faraday's Law but like, I don't get why having a secondary current produces a antiphase secondary current at the same instant. Not all currents produce a direct opposite. Yes I know there is an involvement of inductors, but why doesn't the primary current get some antiphase I1'? Just confused. Thanks.

Taken from Electrical Technology by Theraja, Page 1152 and 1153.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why does an additional primary current I2' exist in a loaded transformer? Yes it is the antiphase of I2, but why does I2 have an antiphase to begin with? I suspect that it is because of some opposition idea that is always associated with EMFs even though it's just a current, but I quite can't get the correct idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I don't get why having a secondary current produces a antiphase secondary current at the same instant*

That is incorrect - it produces an antiphase **primary** current. If it didn't do this then the magnetic flux would have to either grow or fall (due to the secondary current flow) and the transformer output would rise to infinite volts or fall to zero volts instantly.

That doesn't happen (of course) and the only sensible scenario is that (for say a 1:1 transformer), the extra flux due to secondary current flow is exactly matched by a current flow in the primary that produces a cancelling flux of the same magnitude. Thus the secondary current and primary currents that are caused by the secondary load are opposite in phase i.e. 180° apart: -

[image]

Picture from [here](http://www.stades.co.uk/#transformers).

Thus, the induced secondary voltage (either under no load conditions or loaded) remains at a constant value.

Comment: Apologies. I used secondary current terminology because textbooks use I2', which made me haphazardly use the term.

Answer (score 1):

If the input voltage is constant amplitude sinusoid, then the core flux is also a constant amplitude cosinusoid, as the input voltage is balanced by the EMF generated by the changing core flux through the primary windings.

This means a secondary voltage is generated. If the secondary is loaded, then a secondary current will flow.

On no load, the core flux is generated by the small primary magnetising current. When loaded, this additional current would cause the core flux to change. However, we know the core flux has to stay constant amplitude to balance the input voltage. Therefore an additional primary current is drawn to cancel the extra secondary current, to bring the total current back to the level of the original magntising current.

Comment: Does the core flux naturally stay constant? What I mean is does this drawing of current naturally happen? Although this is a different question, why does the flux remain constant?

Comment: In an ideal transformer, the flux and input voltage are related by the equation V=N.d(flux)/dt, where N is the number of primary turns. In a real transformer, winding resistance makes it deviate a few percent from that. The input voltage is balanced by this back EMF, it's this back EMF that's stopping a very high current flow through those ideally zero resistance windings. If the core flux changes due to the secondary current, the input voltage is no longer balanced, and a potentially large current can flow naturally, as much as is needed to restore the flux to flux=integral(voltage)dt.